# relationship between complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Consider the following:

1. Two equilateral triangles inscribed in a circle.
2. The vertices of the large triangle are the geometric images of the three cubic roots of $z$ (a complex number).
3. The small triangle vertices are the midpoints of the sides of the larger triangle.
4. The vertices of the small triangle are the geometric images of the three cubic roots of $w$ (another complex number).

What is the relationship between $w$ and $z$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a^3=z$, $b^3=w$, and $r^3=1$, where $r = \exp\frac{2i\pi}{3}$ is the [primitive cubic root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Then the vertices of the outer triangle are $a, ar, ar^2$, those of the inner triangle are $b, br, br^2$, and, wlog, $b=\frac{a+ar}{2}$.

Now, $$w=b^3=a^3(\frac{1+r}{2})^3=z\frac{1+3r+3r^2+r^3}{8}=-\frac{z}{8}$$

because $r^3=1$ and $1+r+r^2=\frac{1-r^3}{1-r}=0$.

Comment: Depending on how $a$ and $b$ are located, you may also get $b=r\frac{a+ar}{2}$ or $b= r^2\frac{a+ar}{2}$, but the term not influence the result anyway, since you take the third power afterwards.

Comment: I'm lost. Why $r^3=1$ and $1+r+r^2=0$?

Comment: $r$ is the primitive cubic root of unity. See edit.

Comment: Thanks. This statement is true? for a square the primitive root of unity should be r=exp $\Pi i \over 4$

Comment: The $n$-th primitive root of unity if $\exp\frac{2i\pi}{n}$.